# Extract properties from image for MNIST dataset predictor

Tags: python, pandas, image, knn, mnist

I have created a KNN predictor for the MNIST dataset. The dataset contains images of handwritten images. The images are grayscale and measure 28 X 28 pixels. The information of these images is stored in 784 features, each feature corresponds to the intensity of a single pixel in the image. I want to implement this model to new images which are not in the test or training set. I want to write a piece of code which can take an image convert it into 28 X 28 pixels and then store the intensity of each of these pixels as a value in a unique feature. This will enable me to take new images and make predictions on them. What module should I use for this and what procedure should I follow?

Comment: [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenCV and Numpy,
Suppose you take a picture of a digit and save it as 'pic.jpg'

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('pic.jpg', 0) # 0 for greyscale 
resized = cv2.resize(img, (28,28)) 
features = resized.reshape(-1) #converts into single dimension
```

The features array will have the 784 features

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason the white paper behind is black and the text is white in the processed image! My model is not able to make correct predictions because of this.

Comment: After which step do you mean by processed image?

Comment: I plotted the resized variable like this: `plt.imshow(resized, cmap='binary') #Plotting the image
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()`. The black and white are reversed.

Comment: That may be because you are using binary, try plotting using cv2, which is  `cv2.imshow('image', resized)`